# Change attribute field type in SQLite3

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, sqlite

I am trying to change the field type of one of attributes from CharField to DecimalField by doing an empty migrations and populate the new field by filling the migrations log with the following:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations
from decimal import Decimal

def populate_new_col(apps, schema_editor):  #Plug data from 'LastPrice' into 'LastPrice_v1' in the same model class 'all_ks'.
    all_ks = apps.get_model('blog', 'all_ks')
    for ks in all_ks.objects.all():
        if float(ks.LastPrice):  #Check if conversion to float type is possible...
            print ks.LastPrice
            ks.LastPrice_v1, created = all_ks.objects.get_or_create(LastPrice_v1=Decimal(float(ks.LastPrice)*1.0))
        else:  #...else insert None.
            ks.LastPrice_v1, created = all_ks.objects.get_or_create(LastPrice_v1=None)
        ks.save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('blog', '0027_auto_20190301_1600'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(populate_new_col),
    ]
```

But I kept getting an error when I tried to migrate:

```
TypeError: Tried to update field blog.All_ks.LastPrice_v1 with a model instance, <All_ks: All_ks object>. Use a value compatible with DecimalField.
```

Is there something I missed converting string to Decimal?
FYI, ‘LastPrice’ is the old attribute with CharField, and ‘LastPrice_v1’ is the new attribute with DecimalField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`all_ks.objects.get_or_create()` returns an `All_ks` object which you assign to the DecimalField `LastPrice_v1`. So obviously Django complains. Why don't you assign the same `ks`'s `LastPrice`?

```
ks.LastPrice_v1 = float(ks.LastPrice)
```

That said, fiddling around with manual migrations seems a lot of trouble for what you want to achieve (unless you're very familiar with migration code). If you're not, you're usually better off

- creating the new field in code
- migrating
- populating the new field
- renaming the old field
- renaming the new field to the original name
- removing the old field
- migrating again

All steps are vanilla Django operations, with the bonus that you can revert until the very last step (nice to have when things can take unexpected turns as you've just experienced).

Comment: Ok, it's working now for values that can be converted to float, but somehow string values weren't assigned a null value. I have the else part changed to ks.LastPrice_v1 = None

Comment: NVM I get the ValueError exception to work with the try...except . Also I thought populating the new field only works when doing an empty migrations with the RunPython in the operations of the migrations log?

Comment: `try/except ValueError` is the way to go, yes. I'm afraid I cannot help with migration code; unless you're restructuring databases on a regular basis, I believe it's simpler and safer to execute any changes as outlined above.